# <tab> autocompletion not working

Tags: autocompletion

I installed ycm with vimplug and it's working, but I have to press `<C-n>` to scroll through the autocompletion menu.

How can I remap that to `<tab>`?

my .vimrc:

```
call plug#begin()

Plug 'preservim/nerdtree'
Plug 'Townk/vim-autoclose'
Plug 'bfrg/vim-cpp-modern'
Plug 'simeji/winresizer'
Plug 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
Plug 'KarimElghamry/vim-auto-comment'

Plug 'ryanoasis/vim-devicons'
call plug#end()

let g:AutoClosePreserveDotReg = 0

let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf='~/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/.ycm_extra_conf.py'
let g:ycm_confirm_extra_conf=0
let g:ycm_python_binary_path='/usr/bin/python3'


set relativenumber
set tabstop=4
set paste
" let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf = '~/.ycm_extra_conf.py'
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree | wincmd p
autocmd BufEnter * if winnr('$') == 1 && exists('b:NERDTree') && b:NERDTree.isTabTree() | quit | endif

syntax on
set title
set ruler
set encoding=UTF-8
set wildcharm=<tab>

set omnifunc=cppcomplete#CompleteCPP

vnoremap <silent><C-/> :AutoInlineComment<CR>
nnoremap <silent><C-/> :AutoInlineComment<CR>

nmap <F4> :silent !make <CR>


"colorscheme dracula
packadd! dracula
colorscheme dracula
```

Comment: Welcome vi.SE @C0sM1n :) Did you try inoremap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a fist glance, I'd go for something like

```
inoremap Ctrl-i Ctrl-n
```

But there's a cleaner way to achieve it. Please have a look at https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Autocomplete_with_TAB_when_typing_words to update your `~/.vimrc` accordingly.